# Module and Version in GAE/J Cron

Tags: google-app-engine, cron

How can I specify both module and version in GAE/J cron?

I read [this](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/cron) page.

> The target string is prepended to your app's hostname. 
>   It is usually the name of a module. 
>   The cron job will be routed to the default version of the named module. 
>   Note that if the default version of the module changes, 
>   the job will run in the new default version.
>
> If there is no module with the name assigend to target, 
>   the name is assumed to be an app version, and App Engine will attempt to 
>   route the job to that version. See About appengine-web.xml

My understanding is that either module name or version can be specified in `<target>`, but I want to specify both module name and version.

How can I do that?

Comment: were you able to do this?

Answer (score 0):

For achieving your goal, you will need to look for two files (appengine-web.xml, cron.xml), As you already said the target tag of your cron.xml will allow you to set the module or version name, So to be able to do what you need, you can set the app name and module version in appengine-web.xml, Then you can define the module name in the target tag of your cron.xml.

An App Engine Java app must have a file named appengine-web.xml in its WAR, in the directory WEB-INF. This is an XML file whose root element is `<appengine-web-app>`. A minimal file that specifies the application ID, a version identifier, and no static files or resource files looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
  <application>_your_app_id_</application>
  <version>1</version>
  <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
</appengine-web-app>
```

A cron.xml file in the WEB-INF directory of your application (alongside appengine-web.xml) controls cron for your Java application. The following is an example cron.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cronentries>
  <cron>
    <url>/weeklyreport</url>
    <description>Mail out a weekly report</description>
    <schedule>every monday 08:30</schedule>
    <timezone>America/New_York</timezone>
    <target>version-2</target>
  </cron>
</cronentries>
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You will achive your goal if you specify target in such format: "version-dot-module"

this is worked for me:

```
<cron>
    <url>/cron/test-cron</url>
    <description>test-cron</description>
    <schedule>every 1 minutes synchronized</schedule>
    <target>v-5-1-dot-my-module-name</target>
</cron>
```

v-5-1 - version of my module
my-module-name - name of my module